# why alert gives undefined in javascript +jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make inhertance class example in javascript .But I am getting undefined in alert .But I think it should give **"naveen"** in both alert

```
function a (){
          this.name="naveen"
      }
      a.prototype.getname=function(){
          return  "Do :"+ this.name;
      }
          b.prototype= a.prototype;
          function b(){
          }
          alert(new b().name)
      alert(new b().getname())
```

fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/zhvsafaj/

**EDIT**

```
function a (){
          this.name="naveen"
          throw  new Error('cannot create intance')
      }
      a.prototype.getname=function(){
          return  "Do :"+ this.name;
      }
          b.prototype= new a();
          function b(){
          }
          alert(new b().name)
      alert(new b().getname())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a object instance of class

```
b.prototype= new a();
```

so your code be

```
function a (){
          this.name="naveen"
      }

      a.prototype.getname=function(){
          return  "Do :"+ this.name;
      }
      b.prototype = new a();
          function b(){
          }
      alert(new b().name)
      alert(new b().getname())
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/4pcbvmx2/)

Comment: thanks for answering but if "a" is abstract class then can I access "this.name"

Comment: PLEASE CHECK UPDATE .I create abstract class no how I will get "naveen"

Comment: *"It wrong way to assign prototype"*. Nothing wrong with this way of prototypical inheritance. It's just one of the many patterns. It has nuances but it's not *wrong*.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code is that you never set instance property `name` in case of `b` instance. It's assigned in `a` constructor, but not `b`. Note, that `name` is own property, it's not part of `a.prototype` and hence is not shared by `b` instances.

If you want instances of `b` to have property `name` you need to set it similarly you do with `a`. Also note, that it makes little sense to share primitive properties like `name`, the real benefit of prototype pattern is in sharing methods.

Comment: it mean in case of abstract class we didnot get value of property till you cannot defined in main class

Comment: of course, you can't get a property if it's not there.

Comment: so why we get properties in inharitance as above answer .mean using b.prototype= new a();

Comment: Only prototype properties are inherited. So you could put name on prototype of coruse `a.prototype.name` then it would be available as `new b().name`. But again, this is not very useful, because changing `name` in `a` would affect `b` instance.